# htaccess Redirect to another subfolder if URL contains blog in it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silverstripe

I have a sub folder named "blog" inside public_html.

If the url contains blog in it either "blog.mydomain.com" or mydomain.com/blog, I want that to redirect to mydomain.com/blog/index.php.

The problem is that I am using Silversrtipe 3.X and I already have a page created by the name "blog" so whenever I try mydomain.com/blog then instead of redirecting to mydomain.com/blog/index.php it opens up Silverstripe page.

How can i redirect the mydomain.com/blog to "mydomain.com/blog/index.php"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/index.php [L]
```